# Run Time Error 1004 - Error When Another Users Runs Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've built out an Excel macro that will pull information from files on a network drive at work.  It'll condense it into this spreadsheet and use it for some tasks.  When I run it there are no issues and it works exactly as I intend.  However when I had two users test it they had the error described above which prevented the macro from running.

I've looked online and nothing seems to help it.  I've modified the pathing so it would be local and had a user test it locally and they received the same error.  We have the same version of Excel and our permissions aren't different in terms of files or anything.

The error specified this code as the issue:

```
NameMAS = "=Master!R2C1:R" & MASCTA & "C4"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Master", RefersToR1C1:=NameMAS
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MasterID", RefersToR1C1:=MASID

Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & FILE)
Windows(FILE).Activate
  Cells.Select
  Selection.Copy 

Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & FILE)
```

Any assistance would be immensely appreciated as I am completely at a loss as to what to here since I can't test it locally.

Comment: what line errors?

Comment: Does FILE include the file extension?

Comment: Also, why are you opening it again?

Comment: Do they have that FILE in that workbook path?

Comment: Also check out ThisWorkbook vs ActiveWorkbook